# How to access elements in cellTemplate of a datagrid Column

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a datagrid in which columns are added dynamically and their celltemplate is also set in code behind.

```
</UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GridDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White">

        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid" />

    </Grid>
```

In code behind -

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn() { CellTemplate = Resources["GridDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate };

dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Now what I want is to access the grid that is a part of cell template so that I can set its DataContext but I am not able to do so. I have tried using col.CellTemplate.LoadContent() to get the grid but it only gives the grid but I cannot set the datacontext of grid using this.
Can anyone please suggest how can this be done??